# Bootstrap Tooltip Losing Styling after Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

So I have a table that has an icon in each row, if you hover over the icon a bootstrap tooltip appears. But once I make an HTML ajax call to return a new table the tooltips lose their style.

I tried reinitialising the toolips in the ajax success with

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

But I then get the following error message

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Im really stumped on wha to do to fix this

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { 'gtr': gt, 'lower': lower, 'count': 10 },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#customtable').empty();
            $('#customtable').html(data);
            var customtable = $('#games').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 1, "orderable": false }, { "targets": 0, "orderable": false }, { "targets": 4, "orderable": false, "width": "7%" }],
            });
            customtable.fnSort([[0, 'dsc']]);
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        },
        error: function () {
                alert("Something went wrong there");
            }
    });
```

Then the concerning column in table

```
                                        <td><img src="@n.GameVariantIcon" class="player-gamevariant" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@n.GamerVariantName" data-placement="right" /></td>
```

Comment: can you post some code or a fiddle?

Comment: I added some there now!

Comment: you are sure bootstrap is loaded? Is this Ajax function inside `(document).ready(function(){ })`

Comment: Yes I just checked again and it is inside a doc ready. Im lost on this one tbh

Comment: Your code works here: https://jsfiddle.net/tqtqdh14/2/ , which makes me think the tooltip() is being called before the table is ready. you could delay the tooltip initialization. Are you using a custom Boostrap? what version?

Comment: Yes it works on mine on page load, its when I call ajax to return new HTML for the table that they dont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101488/discussion-between-cory-and-bad-dub).